# Place the activites bar and the favorites bar on the same monitor

Tags: multiple-monitors

I have a new installation of 20.04.  I have dual monitors.  On one monitor there is the top (activities) bar.  On the second is the favorites side bar were I have shortcuts to my favorite applications.  If I set one monitor to be the primary display the activities bar moves to that monitor but the favorites move to the other (or visa versa).  How do I get both the favorites and activities on the same monitor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Appearance setting `Show on` and set it to whichever monitor you want:

1. Run `Settings`
2. Select `Appearance`
3. Find `Show on` setting in `Dock` group
4. Select display you want

[image: Screenshot]